# SQL Server Sum Distinct Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example this table, I need to sum this grouped by id and date with distinct

```
id      amt          date
1       100          2018/06/01
1       120          2018/06/02
1       100          2018/06/03
1       100          2018/06/03
1       100          2018/06/03
2       100          2018/06/01
2       100          2018/06/01
2       100          2018/06/01
2       130          2018/06/02
2       130          2018/06/02
2       130          2018/06/02
2       130          2018/06/02
2       100          2018/06/03
```

First i tried

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amt) GROUP BY id
```

But the result are wrong, it's removing duplicate for example on id 1, instead of 320 it only results 220 because it remove the duplicated amt 100.

So I tried

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT amt) GROUP BY id, date
```

But I can't sum it.

Edit: Sorry i forgot to say the result should be

```
id      amt
1       320
2       330
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a long version, but easy to understand query. The below query using CTE should help you

```
with records as
(select distinct id, date, amt from table_name)
select sum (amt), id
from records
group by 
id;
```

Answer (score 1):

tried with below.

```
SELECT id,SUM(DISTINCT amt) as amt,date #tmp from [yourTableName] GROUP BY id, date

select id,amt from #tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, SUM(amt) from (
    select id, SUM(distinct amt) amt, [date] from @tbl
    group by id, [date]
) a group by id
```

First you need to group distinct `amt` grouped by `id` and `date`. Next, you have to to group the result by `id`, summing partially summed `amt` column (in first step we summed only distinct values from particular days).

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT id, 
       Sum(amt) AS amt 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM   mytable) tbl 
GROUP  BY id
```

Output

```
+----+-----+
| id | amt |
+----+-----+
|  1 | 320 |
|  2 | 330 |
+----+-----+
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2d356/14/0

Answer (score 0):

The below query using CTE and Row_number should help you

```
with cte
as
(      
select 1 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/01' as date) date
union all
select 1 id, 120 amt,cast('2018/06/02' as date) date
union all
select 1 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/03' as date) date
union all
select 1 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/03' as date) date
union all
select 1 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/03' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/01' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/01' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/01' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 130 amt,cast('2018/06/02' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 130 amt,cast('2018/06/02' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 130 amt,cast('2018/06/02' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 130 amt,cast('2018/06/02' as date) date
union all
select 2 id, 100 amt,cast('2018/06/03' as date) date
)
select id,sum(amt) as sum1 from 
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id,date order by id,date) s1 from cte
) b
where s1=1
group by id
```